# Cannot access Einstein Wave Analytics app that someone else created

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics

Background info:
Both my colleague & I have :

- Profile = 'System Administrator' with 'View all data' & 'Modify all data' checkbox
- Permission Set = 'Einstein Wave Administrator' (shown on screenshot) & it auto assigns 'Analytics Cloud - Wave Analytics Platform' to both of us.

[image: Wave Permissions]

After my colleague creates the dashboard in the app I try giving access to myself as **Manager**. But when I try to access the dashboard, I get the error below:

[image: getDependentLenses]

> Cannot read property 'getDependentLenses' of undefined

Why do I get this error? Is there something wrong with my SFDC environment or is there some other settings which I have to check. I remember in other SFDC environments I able to access Wave Dashboards made by other people just fine (even without granting access through the app)

Comment: I had a similar issue, wherein a lens was created by me and was used in the dashboard, but the lens/dataset wasn't shared with other user, so there was a same error which you have reported.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps
make sure that app and datasets used by that dashboard/app is public app not in private app.
If dataset is in private app you cannot open that dashboard 
and have app share to entire organization as viewer

Answer (score -1):

Possibilities:

1. Dataset/ Dashboard/ Lens is in Private App.
2. App/ Dataset/ Dashboard/ Lens is in that app where you don't have access.

Kind regards,

Shaleen Basak

Comment: This appears to be the same information as the existing answer from 5 years ago.